# sorting array by date unexpected result

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array which contains dates and sometime not :

```
const activities = [
    { title: 'Hikin'},
  { title: 'Hiking', date: '2020-12-23' },
  { title: 'Shopping', date: '2020-12-18' },
]
```

i want to sort based on dates with this function :

```js
const activities = [
    { title: 'Hikin'},
  { title: 'Hiking', date: '2020-12-23' },
  { title: 'Shopping', date: '2020-12-18' },
]

const sortedActivities = activities.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date)  - new Date(a.date))

console.log(sortedActivities.map(item => {
    return item.title;
}))
```

But the problem is , the items without date stay on top. I would like the items with date to be prioritized over the items that dont contain a date value.

The sorting works , except the ones without date goes on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your comparison method in sort function. Like this:

```
activities.sort((a, b) => {
  if (!a.date && !b.date) return 0; // no need to sort
  if (!a.date) return 1;
  if (!b.date) return -1;
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Comment: @AdnanAhmed It is working. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/mvp1nadc/1/ . Can you post dataset for which it not working? So that we can solve that problem also, if present.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is removing the date first and then applied the filter and in last I just merged the sorted data and data without date.

```js
const activities = [
  { title: 'Hikin'},
  { title: 'Hiking', date: '2020-12-23' },
  { title: 'Shopping', date: '2020-12-18' },
];

const activitesWithoutDate = activities.filter(a => a.date === undefined);
const activitesWithDate = activities.filter(a => a.date !== undefined);

const sortedActivities = activitesWithDate.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date)  - new Date(a.date));

console.log([...sortedActivities, ...activitesWithoutDate].map(item => item.title ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [epoch point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) as fallback for items that does not have `date` attribute:

```
 const activities = [
    { title: 'Hikin'},
    { title: 'Hiking', date: '2020-12-23' },
    { title: 'Shopping', date: '2020-12-18' },
 ]

 const sortedActivities = activities.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date || '1970-01-01')  - new Date(a.date||'1970-01-01'))

 console.log(sortedActivities.map(item => {
return item.title;
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const activities = [
    { title: 'Hikin'},
    { title: 'Hiking', date: '2020-12-23' },
    { title: 'Hikin2'},
    { title: 'Shopping', date: '2020-12-18' },
    { title: 'Hikin3'},
]

const sortedActivities = activities.sort((a, b) => {
    if(!b.date && !a.date) { return 0 }; // if both don't have date do not sort.
    if(!b.date) { return -1 }; // a comes first
    if(!a.date) { return 1 }; // b comes first
    let calValue = new Date(b.date)  - new Date(a.date); 
    return calValue;
})

console.log(sortedActivities.map(item => {
    return item.title;
}))
```